# google big query command line executing complex query giving error unexpected '('

Tags: bash, google-bigquery, syntax-error, command-line-interface, sh

I have following command line query to be executed on google big query console.
It consists a lot of REGEXP
It is throwing error

-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false select s1.ID., REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(UPPER(s1.d),r'(\|/|\?|\-|&)', ""),r'\s+',"_") D, CAST(s1.F as INT64) F FROM `myproject.mydataset.mytable` s1 where regexp_contains(s1.f,r'^[+-]?[[:digit:]]+$') and exists ( select xyz from `myproject.mydataset.mytable`  s2 where s1.d=s2.d)
```

I want to run this query in command line.

query

```
select s1.ID., REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(UPPER(s1.d),r'(\|/|\?|\-|&)', ""),r'\s+',"_") D, CAST(s1.F as INT64) F FROM `myproject.mydataset.mytable` s1 where regexp_contains(s1.f,r'^[+-]?[[:digit:]]+$') and exists ( select xyz from `myproject.mydataset.mytable`  s2 where s1.d=s2.d)
```

This query executes fine in GUI GBQ

Any help would be appreciated to execute this code in command line .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terminal might mess up some characters when pasting long and complex text, I would suggest saving your query as a .sql file and then just run:

```
bq query `cat /path-to-file/test.sql`
```

Comment: thanks that work. Actually i wanted to run this command in python using os.system() can you suggest how to do it? and eventually main query is ('bq mk --use_legacy_sql=false --description "This is copy view" --view `cat q_cmd.txt` --project_id '+dest_project+" "+dest_dataset+"."+dest_view) which i want to run in python can you please suggest me how to do it?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are trying to run CLI commands with python? If not, you can check out google-cloud for python (https://gcloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery/query.html).
This will let you interact with BigQuery pretty easily using python. Thought you will need to use DDL instead of 'bq mk --view'. i.e
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW temp.myview AS (SELECT '1' as col)